# Twitter Bootstrap column height change without gaps in the column grid?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make bootstrap 4.5 one column height change bigger so that there would be no gaps in the grid? See the picture below (test 2 and test 4 columns should be with no gap and ONLY test 1 should be higher, other the same height).

Start position is that all the columns are equal height. I might use jquery to expand the "test 1" column.

Relevant code here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 400px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 200px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 200px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 200px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 4
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you *have* to use Bootstrap layout for this? This would be ***much*** simpler in a CSS flexbox layout.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that BS 4.5 has Flex layout also. This might help get it working? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `min-height: 200px;` instead of just setting the height.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 400px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="min-height: 200px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 200px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 200px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                    test 4
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant that 2,3 and 4 would be 200 px high and only test 1 would be 400px. Test4 should be right below the test 2, no gap...

Thanks for your suggestion, it was good. My post was a bit ambiguous

Comment: @coder Ahh, this is a very different question and it completely defeats the purpose of using a grid.  A grid is designed to keep things in order exactly how it is now. I would suggest organizing this differently. Such as 2 grids side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it working with two flex columns but then the order does not work in phone layout (it will be 1,3,...). See the images:

[image]

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="" style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                test 1
            </div>
            <div class="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                test 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">

            <div class="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                test 2
            </div>
            <div class="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #333;">
                test 4 sigh
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And actually this is possible by making my own float columns. They seem to work without gaps (float left always fills the space correctly).